# How can I apply a custom filter to ng-repeat only when there is a value in the textfield?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that I'm trying to filter through.  I have several filters being used, but one of them is to filter objects out that don't fall in a range of years specified by the user. Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="minYear" placeholder="Start Year">
<input type="text" ng-model="maxYear" placeholder="End Year">
```

Here is the ng-repeat

```
<img ng-src="{{pic.imgPath}}" ng-repeat="pic in pictures 
  | orderBy : 'title' | filter:{other filters} | filter:yearFilterFunction"/>
```

Here is the yearFilterFunction that I am using to filter. And note, this works when there are values present. So if the picture was from 2001, and you put in 2000 for the minYear and 2005 for the maxYear, it will show. **But When the page loads, and there is nothing in these values....nothing in the array shows up in the repeat.  I tried declaring these variables beforehand, but then it just looks funny when the user goes in and sees 1900 and 2016 in these two inputs.**
Here is the Javascript

```
$scope.minYear = 1900;
$scope.maxYear = 2016;
$scope.yearFilterFunction = function(picture){
    return (picture.year >= $scope.minYear && picture.year <= $scope.maxYear);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will work for you : a working [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yufeng/oq4zgwb0/)

The point is, you don't need to set the `minYear` and `maxYear` beforehand, so the value will be treated as `undefined` at beginning, but when user type anything and erase that value to empty, the model value will be changed to ''. So the regex will suit this situation pretty well :

```
$scope.yearFilterFunction = function(picture){
            var regObj = new RegExp('[0-9]+');
        return (
    (!regObj.test($scope.minYear) || picture.year >= $scope.minYear)
    && (!regObj.test($scope.maxYear) || picture.year <= $scope.maxYear)
);
```

Comment: Can I ask what regObj.test() does?

Answer (score 0):

This handles all the 4 cases 
1) when both are set
2)when only minYear is set
3) when only maxYear is set
4) when both are not set . In this case display all

```
$scope.yearFilterFunction = function(picture){
         return 
         ($scope.minYear && $scope.maxYear && picture.year >= $scope.minYear &&     picture.year <= $scope.maxYear) ||      
         ($scope.minYear && !scope.maxYear  && picture.year >= $scope.minYear) ||
         ($scope.maxYear && !scope.minYear  && picture.year <= $scope.maxYear) ||
         (!$scope.maxYear && !scope.minYear);
     }
```

Comment: This functions handles all the four cases 1) when both min and max are set

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: @NathanT Can I get an upvote  if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I used an alternate approach to solve this issue. I wrote a custom filter which will accept the start year and end year and then filter out the years in between them. Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/g8c7ymhp/).

**Filter**

```
myApp.filter("yearFilter", function() {
  return function(years, startYear, endYear) {
    var filteredYears = years;
    if (!isNaN(startYear)) {
      filteredYears = _.filter(filteredYears, function(year) {
        return year >= startYear;
      });
    }
    if (!isNaN(endYear)) {
      if (isNaN(startYear) || (parseInt(startYear) < parseInt(endYear))) {
        filteredYears = _.filter(filteredYears, function(year) {
          return year <= endYear;
        });
      }
    }
    return filteredYears;
  }
});
```

Basically the filter is checking whether your start year/end year is a number and based on that it will do the filtering. It will also handle situations where only the start year or the end year is valid. I have assumed a scenario where if the end year is lesser that the start year, it will only filter by the start year.

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="minYear" placeholder="Start Year">
  <input type="text" ng-model="maxYear" placeholder="End Year">
  <div ng-repeat="year in years | yearFilter: minYear: maxYear">
    {{year}}
  </div>
```